# How to switch a relative path to version dependency while building?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am having a monorepo with below structure,

```
root
 |__ lib1
      |__ pyproject.toml
 |__ lib2
      |__ pyproject.toml
```

In the lib2, I have below definition,

```
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
lib1 = {path = "../lib1", develop=true}
```

Now, when I build lib2 as wheel, I want the above definition to change like below

```
lib1 = "${env:MYVER}"
```

where `${env:MYVER}` is the environment variable set in powershell.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. I think maybe it is possible with [_`hatch`_](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/context/) (instead of Poetry), not entirely sure.

Comment: Thanks. I tried hatch as well but I am struggling to get this work in it as well.

Comment: I would probably ask [here for hatch](https://github.com/pypa/hatch/discussions) and/or [here for poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/discussions) if I were you. -- I am quite sure it would be fairly easy to do with a setuptools' `setup.py`, even though it is a bad practice in any case. Which leads me to this: maybe it is an "[X Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)". If you edited your question to explain why you need this, it might be more productive.